# ldd but for interlibrary dependencies?

Tags: linux, compile, gcc, shared-libraries

Is there a tool like ldd which shows which libraries an executable depends on,but for inter-library dependencies.

For example one shared library needs another one.How to get the dependencies.

I'm in a situtation where gcc tries to build an .so compiled library file but complains with "/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libint.1.so when searching for -lint.1"

I need to know which libraries it depends on and which version is it looking for?
There is a int.so but how can I find which version is it and which version gcc is looking for?

Comment: `ldd` works perfectly fine for libraries. What you mention is also not an error but a warning.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment states, just run ldd against the .so you are interested in, e.g.:

```
ldd -v /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff93789000)
    libblas.so.3 => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (0x00007f7982fc9000)
    libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3(0x00007f7982c9e000)
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Any tools which work with ELF executables will work identically with ELF shared libraries. In the end, they both use the same dynamic linking mechanism.

But if you want a nice overview of *direct* dependencies of each library, pax-utils has **`lddtree`**:

```
$ lddtree /bin/curl
/bin/curl (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    libcurl.so.4 => /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4
        libnghttp2.so.14 => /usr/lib/libnghttp2.so.14
        libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libidn2.so.0
            libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/libunistring.so.2
        libssh2.so.1 => /usr/lib/libssh2.so.1
        libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/libpsl.so.5
        libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
            libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
            libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0
            libkeyutils.so.1 => /usr/lib/libkeyutils.so.1
            libresolv.so.2 => /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2
        libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3
        libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3
        libcom_err.so.2 => /usr/lib/libcom_err.so.2
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

You can obtain the same information by:

1. Using `readelf -d <binary>` or `scanelf --needed <binary>` to list its *direct* dependencies (any ELF binary works, both executable and shared).
2. Repeating step 1 for all libraries you found in the previous iteration. Rinse and repeat until you have all information needed to build the dependency tree.

Comment: ok but how do I find the API version e.g of libnghttp2 that bin/curl needs? or is that what the .so.14 means? that is version 14?

Comment: Yes, that's the soname version that curl needs. It might not necessarily correspond to the package version (developers use it to indicate breaking ABI changes), but regardless you just need a package that provides that file (apt-file search libnghttp2.so.14, yum whatprovides libnghttp2.so.14, etc).